# What installer options are there for Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, visual-studio-express

So Microsoft released Visual Studio 2012 Express for desktop apps.  That's great, but how does one create an installer for open source apps that are built in Visual Studio Express?  There are no installer templates available by default, and they have disabled browsing the online gallery.  Sure, I could purchase something like InstallShield, but that kind of defeats the purpose of an open source application if you ask me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the open source [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) or [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) tools to create fairly nice installers.

Since both should work without the Visual Studio integration that Express won't give you, they should both be usable (even if not quite as nicely) without problems.

Comment: +1 Forgot about NSIS despite having just installed something with it a few days ago.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it gives two options.  Not sure which I'll use yet, but I'm sure both would work.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

I would use Inno Setup, which is a little easier to learn than most other setup programs.
I have a link here:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/