# How to create .exe file of my vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have developed an application on visual studio express 2012 (trial version) which is working as expected on my system but I am unable to decipher how to share this application with my colleagues. I got to know that I will have to create a .exe file which will run on other systems. Please suggest me something.

Comment: Erm, _Build -> Build <yourappname>_?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyz1h6zd.aspx

Comment: Did you say exe but mean an **Installer**?

Comment: @tim: yes correct installer

Comment: Here's a rather radical suggestion, how about you edit your question to say what you _really_ mean instead of assuming everyone on here is a mindreader?

Answer (score 0):

The output is typically in one of these directories based on your build  configuration unless you manually changed the build directory:

```
[project root directory]/bin/debug/x86
[project root directory]/bin/debug
[project root directory]/bin/Release/x86
[project root directory]/bin/Release
```

When you send the program to your colleagues you may need to include some of the other files in this directory, particularly .dll files if you used any external libraries.

Comment: Yes that is fine. Output will be in the above mentioned directories. I have used external libraries. Let me try again tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: That depends on your project.  If you are not using any external libraries or data files then you just need `[Your project name].exe`.  If there are other `.dll` files in there also they are probably needed.  `.pdb` files are used for debugging and are not required, but they can be helpful if there is an error in the program.  the `.xml` files are not needed, they are used by visual studio to generate intellisense when the output is referenced by another program.  You can safely ignore the vshost.exe file that is created also.

Answer (score 0):

I use Inno Setup, linked in this Stack Overflow article. (At home I've done some stuff on my own, and I use VS 2012 Express, which doesn't have the ability to create an installer/setup package)

Inno Setup works on Win 7 & 8 (and my old Vista laptop). Don't know about the others...

[What installer options are there for Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654380/what-installer-options-are-there-for-visual-studio-2012-express-for-desktop)